# Why does sed sometimes truncate when replacing?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm writing a shell script to resolve `https://t.co` links in Tweets (these are shortened links that redirect to somewhere else). I've written the following function:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
function resolvelinks {
    local content="$1"
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a foundlinks < <(grep -o 'https://t.co/[a-zA-Z0-9]*' <<< "$1")
    for link in "${foundlinks[@]}" ; do
        resultinglink=$(curl -s -D - "$link" | grep location: | sed 's/^location: //g')
        content=$(sed "s|${link}|${resultinglink}|" <<< "$content")
    done
    echo "$content"
}
resolvelinks "$@"
```

Suppose I have the following tweet text in a file named `tweet.txt`:

```
Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2 https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1
```

When I have one `t.co` link, like below, the function works as expected:

```
$ ./resolvelinks.sh "$(cat tweet.txt)"
Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/
```

However, when I have two or more `t.co` links, it truncates the result and I'm not sure why:

```
./resolvelinks.sh "$(cat tweet.txt)"
Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

 https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1
```

Why does this happen with sed and grep, and how would I fix/avoid it? *(I had to put spaces in the `t.co` links in my examples because SO won't let me include a URL shortener in my question)*

For reference, I'm expecting the output to have two resolved links:

```
./resolvelinks.sh "$(cat tweet.txt)"
Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/ https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1
```

**As requested, bash trace:**

```
+ resolvelinks 'Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2 https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1'
+ local 'content=Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2 https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r -d '' -a foundlinks
++ grep -o 'https://t.co/[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
+ for link in "${foundlinks[@]}"
++ curl -s -D - https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2
++ grep location:
++ sed 's/^location: //g'
+ resultinglink=$'https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/\r'
|' sed 's|https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2|https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/
+ content='Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

 https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1'om/wwdc20/
+ for link in "${foundlinks[@]}"
++ curl -s -D - https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1
++ grep location:
++ sed 's/^location: //g'
+ resultinglink=$'https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1\r'
|' sed 's|https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1|https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1
+ content='Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

'https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1
+ echo -e 'Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

'https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1
Apple is moving WWDC 2020 to online only

 https://twitter.com/MKBHD/status/1238499066323046400/photo/1
```

Comment: just a general question ... have you verified each step in the process, eg, the contents of the array, the contents of the variables on each pass through the loop, the data being passed to `sed/grep`, the results being generated by `sed/grep` ... ? also, can you update the question with what you're expecting as the output for the problematic link?

Comment: @markp, yes, I've debugged every line individually - each seems to be performing as expected

Comment: so you've verified the array contains a single entry and that's exactly what you want, right?  `typeset -p foundlinks => declare -a foundlinks=([0]=$'https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2\nhttps://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1')` (spaces added to get past SO's disabling of URL shorteners)

Comment: `for link in "${foundlinks[@]}" ; do echo "1.$link.1"; done` => `1.https://t.co/ xw72yfhUR2
https://t.co/ ddCAppLrL1.1` ... single entry in array that contains an embedded carriage return

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29); `array=( $(...) )` is not by any means a best-practices means to break a command's output into an array, *especially* if you expect that array to be one-item-per-line.

Comment: And using backticks instead of `$( )` invites other bugs; they don't nest well, and change the interpretation of backslashes within them. The modern syntax has been standard since 1992; there's no reason not to use it today.

Comment: Why is there a space after `https://t.co/` in the input strings?

Comment: @markp Input is actually coming from a file, I just omitted that part to simplify the question - I fixed it in my question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: That shouldn't affect links in code blocks, does it?

Comment: @wcarhart I created tweet.txt and manually ran through your steps ... still getting a single array element with an embedded carriage return

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The problem persists even when using `$(...)` and `read` to build the array - updated the question

Comment: as a quick-n-dirty 'fix', pipe the` grep` output through `tr '\n' '>space<'`; this should break the 2x entries into separate components and allow for 2 entries in the array; `foundlinks=( $(grep -o 'https://t.co/[a-zA-Z0-9]*' <<<  "${content}" | tr '\n' ' ') )`

Comment: @markp With the code above (updated per CharlesDuffy's comments), I get two links in `foundlinks` - I don't think the issue is due to the length of the array being 1

Comment: Can you [edit] a trace of the execution of `bash -x yourscript` into the question?

Comment: yeah, accomplishes the same thing (effectively replacing '\n' with ' ') but a bit more precise

Comment: (moving back away from the immediate issue towards general code-quality notes, note that `echo -e` is also bad practice; see the excellent [explanation by Stephane Chazelas on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113), and/or the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX `echo` specification itself](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) advising `printf` instead).

Comment: BTW, as a heads-up for what to look for to diagnose this in the future, you can see `\r`s in `$'...'`-style quoting in the `set -x` log; that's a giveaway for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `curl` response has `\r\n` at the end of each line, and the `\r` character is being left in `$resultinglink`. You can remove it in the `sed` command.

```
resultinglink=$(curl -s -D - "$link" | grep location: | sed -e 's/^location: //' -e $'s/\\\r//')
```